# printer rolls out paper without printing

Tags: printing

i'm new to ubuntu and pretty itillitarate. I installed my epson 235 easily. connected the usb , install. I then created a 2 page document, the printer duly rolled out 2 pages but without actually printing. 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: if you go to the PRINTERS folder; look for the icon for the 235; right-click on it; select PROPERTIES: look in the MAKE & MODEL line; drag the window to the right to see all the text; please copy what is there; and paste it back here please; we are talking about an XP-235 from Epson? which version of ubuntu are you using please; I reckon for 64bit Ubuntu, one would best have epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.19-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb installed; it was issued 12th March 2018 by Epson

Comment: It is indeed an Epson, i tried a test page and the printer issued a vertical column of F's at the left side of the page. This is the requested copy paste :Generic ESC/P Dot Matrix PrinterFoomatic/epson(recommended)

Comment: sorry, i continue : the version is , i believe 174.10 (my son installed this) and indeed 64bit. Many thanks

Comment: As Epson has several models (Picturemate, StylusSX, StylusTX, and XP series) that utilize the 235 descriptor in the model name, this question would be much improved if you would be so kind as to [edit] in the exact model name.  If you do so and drop me a comment you'll earn an upvote from me (and likely others with the same model and problem as you.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going to the PRINTERS folder; delete the icon for 235 that is there; (it is not working); 
for the Epson XP-235, Epson supply drivers; install those. 
go here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX and type in the model number (XP-235?) and for 64bit Ubuntu, click to download epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.19-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Ubuntu may well offer to "open" the package: if so, accept; as that should mean gdebi installer will install the package as it is downloaded; that should install the needed drivers;

instead, if you just SAVE the package as it is downloaded, then go to where it was downloaded to; (the Downloads folder?) and right-click on the package; select install with gdebi installer; things should work after that

Comment: Your link is broken mate.

Comment: sorry about this Mr Elder Geek; I have just clicked on it, and it works fine for me: not sure how to explain or resolve this

Comment: To clarify, it does load a page, the content of which is "The page you requested is unavailable"

Comment: oh dear; it still works fine for me: for anyone else having difficulties, this is the Epson portal page for linux and then type the printer model in http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Comment: The link in your comment works as expected. I suggest that you [edit] your answer to include [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020843/printer-rolls-out-paper-without-printing/1021417?noredirect=1#comment1660447_1021417) as comments can be deleted for numerous reasons without warning.